# Call to decision table from drools' drl file

Tags: drools

Can we have drl and decision table in 1 kieSession?

If I have a decision table in xls and my drl has a rule that need a result from that decision table, is it possible for me to call to the decision table within a rule inside the drl file?

```
Rule ""
when
    Car( color == red )
    //I want to call a decision table here and check its result
then
    update($xlsResult)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't invoke rule by it's name because rules are invoked automatically if their conditions are met.

Comment: If I have a Decision Table KieSession, can I fireAllRule in another drl file?

rule "Roaming Lookup"
    when  
        $request : Request( color == "RED" )
        $dt : KieDecisionTable( )
    then
        //Lookup Table
        $dt.getKSession().insert($request)
     $dt.getKSession().fireAllRules();

end

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have a public method in the fact that does the actual call to the decision table and return the result.

From the drl file you can just trigger the public method of the fact to get the data.